# Difference Between Class Reference And Class Instance

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

Given that both of these calls to getQualifiedClassName return the same thing (mx:Label), how would one go about programatically differentiating between an instance of a class and a reference to the class...

```
    var lab1:Label=new Label();
    var lab2:Class=Label;
    var qcn1:String=getQualifiedClassName(lab1);
    var qcn2:String=getQualifiedClassName(lab2);
```

In other words, how could I know that lab1 is of type Label, while lab2 is type "Class".

typeof() simply returns "object" for both... getQualifiedClassName returns "mx.controls::Label" for both...

What do I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `is` operator:

```
>>> lab1 is Label
true
>>> lab1 is Class
false
>>> lab2 is Label
false
>>> lab2 is Class
true
```

Also (although this should be trivially true) `lab2 == Label`.

Answer (score 1):

trace( Sprite is Class ); // true
trace( new Sprite() is Class ); // false

Answer (score 1):

To test things in more details in the future, you can always use

```
import flash.utils.describeType;

trace(describeType(new Label()));
trace(describeType(Label));
```

This will give you 2 `XML` outputs. Here you will be able to clearly see the difference.
I have provided 2 here for you for the `Point` class, since point is a relatively simple class compared to `DisplayObjects` and any class that extends off them.

Instance.

```
<type name="flash.geom::Point" base="Object" isDynamic="false" isFinal="false" isStatic="false">
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <constructor>
    <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="true"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="true"/>
  </constructor>
  <variable name="x" type="Number"/>
  <variable name="y" type="Number"/>
  <accessor name="length" access="readonly" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point"/>
  <method name="clone" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point"/>
  <method name="add" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="equals" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="Boolean">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="subtract" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="normalize" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="offset" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="void">
    <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="toString" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="String"/>
</type>
```

Class

```
<type name="flash.geom::Point" base="Class" isDynamic="true" isFinal="true" isStatic="true">
  <extendsClass type="Class"/>
  <extendsClass type="Object"/>
  <accessor name="prototype" access="readonly" type="*" declaredBy="Class"/>
  <method name="polar" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
    <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="interpolate" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="3" type="Number" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <method name="distance" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="Number">
    <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
    <parameter index="2" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
  </method>
  <factory type="flash.geom::Point">
    <extendsClass type="Object"/>
    <constructor>
      <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="true"/>
      <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="true"/>
    </constructor>
    <variable name="x" type="Number"/>
    <variable name="y" type="Number"/>
    <accessor name="length" access="readonly" type="Number" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point"/>
    <method name="clone" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point"/>
    <method name="add" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
      <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
    </method>
    <method name="equals" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="Boolean">
      <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
    </method>
    <method name="subtract" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="flash.geom::Point">
      <parameter index="1" type="flash.geom::Point" optional="false"/>
    </method>
    <method name="normalize" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="void">
      <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
    </method>
    <method name="offset" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="void">
      <parameter index="1" type="Number" optional="false"/>
      <parameter index="2" type="Number" optional="false"/>
    </method>
    <method name="toString" declaredBy="flash.geom::Point" returnType="String"/>
  </factory>
</type>
```

The Main differences being `base="Object"` and `base="Class"` and also the Class one has a `<factory />` node. There are obviosuly more differences, but those are usually the parts I concentrate on the most.